# Can cosine kernel be understood as a case of Beta distribution?

Tags: distributions, kernel-smoothing, beta-distribution

As noted by Wand and Jones (1995), most standard kernels may be seen as a case of

$$ K(x;p) = \{ 2^{2p+1} \; \mathrm{B}(p+1,p+1) \}^{-1} \; (1-x^2)^p \;\boldsymbol{1}_{\{|x|<1\}} $$

family, where $\mathrm{B}(\cdot,\cdot)$ is a Beta function. Different values of $p$ lead to rectangular ($p=0$), Epanechnikov ($p=1$), biweight ($p=2$) and triweight ($p=3$) kernels.

Can cosine kernel (as understood in R's `density` function),

$$ \frac{1}{2} (1 + \cos(\pi x)) \;\boldsymbol{1}_{\{|x|<1\}} $$

also be thought as a member of this family? If so, what is an appropriate value of $p$ for it? After doing some simulations I guess that $\approx 2.35$ is pretty close, but (how) can I find the proper without simulation? If not, can it be approximated using beta distribution?

---

Wand, M. P. and Jones, M. C. (1995).
*Kernel Smoothing.*
Chapman and Hall, London.

Comment: Beta function with integer arguments is just some ratio of factorials, but for non-integer arguments I doubt that it would simplify to anything useful; and it is certainly just a *number* depending on $p$ so there is no way you can obtain a cosine function from this expression.

Comment: @amoeba still, can it be approximated? And the second question is: how did they find the values for the other kernels?

Comment: @Tim, what do you mean by "how did they find"? Just by plugging in?

Comment: @amoeba you don't need the whole cosine though, only the curve between $\{-1,1\}$. As we know it's an infinite sum of polynomials (Taylor expansion around zero).

Comment: @ChristophHanck right, this was obvious, I retract this question :) Somehow I started from thinking about it in terms of Beta distribution rather then focusing directly on it.

Comment: @Firebug Well clearly it's an infinite sum of polynomials, but $K$ in this question is not an infinite sum, there is only one single term.

Comment: @amoeba indeed. Wondering how an infinite kernel space could be defined in terms of the Beta distribution then (which would bring us back to the cosine, but still).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The cosine kernel is not a beta distribution.

Note that the following things are all true of the standard cosine density:

- $f(0)=1$
- $f(0.5)=0.5$
- The right half of this density is rotationally symmetric about $x=\frac12$: (i.e. considering the other two properties it implies $1-f(x)=f(1-x)$ )

But no beta density on (-1,1) will have all
 these properties together.

The symmetric beta kernel density can be written as:

$g(x;a)= \frac{(1-x^2)^{a-1}}{\text{B}(a,a)2^{2a-1}}\,,\:-1<x<1\,,\:a>0$

For example, the first condition implies a $a$ of about $3.38175$ ($p=2.38175$). The second implies an $a$ of 1 ($p=0$).

However, values of $a$ near that choice of $a$ (3.38175) gives densities really quite close to the cosine.

[This is quite close to your $p=2.35$ (since $p=a-1$); a range of values in this region give densities similar to the cosine.]

The smallest absolute deviation in density happens for $p\approx 2.3575$ -- not that minimizing the absolute deviations will make the properties most alike.

Here's the cosine and beta (with $p=2.3575$):

[image: Plot of cosine and beta kernels]

Even though they're not the same, they're quite alike in shape.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks. It is interesting to learn that while it is impossible to get exact match, we can get so close by approximation.

Comment: The value of $3.38\ldots$ should be no surprise, because a third-order Taylor series approximation to the cosine suggests $a=\pi^2/4+1=3.46\ldots$.